# unable to trigger outside function in string function

Tags: javascript

the goal is to call save inside of the text script when its executed by eval.
i tried the following but its not working

when i pass in save its not being called because i dont see the save print statement.

```js
const save = (current) =>{
    console.log('save');
}

var script = `function rune_rule() { 
    save()
}`;

const run_server_rules_filter = async () => {
        eval(script);
        await rune_rule(save); 
};

run_server_rules_filter();
```

i dont see the save print statement so i know its not working

i tried what i wrote but it didnt work and chatgpt didnt know either

Comment: Small note: If your functions don't rely on `this` bindings, just declare them as normal functions? Also, if you're using `const`, don't use `var`, use `let` (both `const` and `let` are scoped in the same way, `var` is scoped radically different). But probably most important: _don't use eval_. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve here? Because if you need `eval` for it, there's almost certainly a better way to do this (even if that's a dynamic import for the same string data: now it runs in isolation without access to anything in _your_ code, instead of being able to destroy everything)

Comment: @fdomn-m i am calling the function right here::
 await rune_rule(save);

Comment: `rune_rule()` doesn't have any parameters, why are you passing `save` as an argument?

Comment: And `save()` does have a parameter (although it doesn't usde it), but you're not passing an argument to it.

Comment: The variable is `script`, not `rule.script`.

Comment: Changing `eval(rule.script)` to `eval(script)` makes it work.